# Space Management in SQL Database

Tags: data-structures, database

I am trying to create a new type of **MMORTS game**.

### Current Situation

**Everyday each user deletes and creates** : 1,500 rows of data in diff. tables but in 1 database (all tables data are inter-related to data of other tables)
**Each Row estimated size** : 1KB
**Max user per database** : 100,000 users
**Total Space Consumed everyday** : 0.15 TB

**Actual Users in the Game** : 10,000,000 users (split in different databases)

### Problem

According to me if I delete a row in SQL it is not being deleted permanently and will still consume space in the database. If this happens, then in near future all my server are likely to crash.

Can anyone tell me if i am going wrong anywhere or suggest me any solution to this problem? I know this question cannot be understood easily so please feel free to ask any doubts you have regarding this question.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @Developper_Nation How are the rows deleted? Are they really deleted with an sql DELETE statement? If so, why do you day that SQL does not delete rows permanently? Or are you simply setting a flag on rows to indicate that they are deleted?

Comment: i am using SQL Server 2008 and i am firing sql "Delete" query and i know it does not free any space so i fire shrink database every 3 hour

Answer (score 0):

Some databases may use archive techniques, but I doubt you can rely on that. You need to use some scaling solution like sharding or partitioning and should be able to just drop/discard outdated data whenever it is no longer needed (which should be more efficient than regular SQL DELETE).

BTW 10M active users is like 1/10 of facebook, which is a lot

Comment: actually according to my estimate calculation in about "3 years" it is likely to reach 10M with 1500 remaining constant every year.